# perl print one output when matched a string

Tags: perl

I am writing this simple code to get alert email when "error" found on my log.

The question is I want to get only one alert per scan my code is generate number of alert based number of error matched on the file.

```
open (LOG, "<$log") || die 'Could not OPEN log file';
while ($loglines = <LOG> ) {
if ($loglines =~ /Error/) { 
    print "Error on the log \n";
}
 }
 close (LOG);
```

the result looks like

> Error on the log
>
> Error on the log
>
> Error on the log
>
> Error on the log
>
> Error on the log

Instead I want just one print "Error on the log" that i way I can get one email when error matched on the log file. What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
open my $LOG, "<", $log or die "Could not OPEN log file $log";
while (my $loglines = <$LOG>) {
  if ($loglines =~ /Error/) { 
   print "Error on the log\n";
   last;
  }
}
close($LOG);
```

There are a lot of improvements in that.  The most important change is the addition of `last;`; it terminates the loop on the first match.

Other changes are:

- Use of lexical file handle.
- Use of three-argument open.
- Use of '`or`' instead of '`||`'.
- Local variable for `$loglines` (assuming you didn't need/use it elsewhere).
- Error message identifies which file could not be opened (easier to debug!).
- No trailing space on the printed message line.

Some would prefer a label added to the loop and then an explicit use of that in the `last` statement:

```
open my $LOG, "<", $log or die "Could not OPEN log file $log";
LOG_READER:
while (my $loglines = <$LOG>) {
  if ($loglines =~ /Error/) { 
   print "Error on the log\n";
   last LOG_READER;
  }
}
close($LOG);
```

I'm not convinced there is much gain here, assuming there are no enclosing loops.  If there are any enclosing loops, then use the label.

I assume you are using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the top of your script?  If not, then do so.  Perl experts use them to make sure they avoid making silly mistakes; Perl novices should use them for the same reasons.

Comment: thanks so very much, working perfectly. hope some one give up vote ..I don't have enough credential for up vote. thanks again!!